# Different DTU - Service tier between Master and Replica azure database

Tags: performance, azure-sql-database

I've got an azure db with replica.
the master has:
Standard S6-  400 DTUs
the replica has:
Standard S3-  100 DTUs

Is it a problem for a replica to be in a different service tier and dtu than master?

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the purpose of the replica. If it's there to provide high availability, after the failover it won't be able to support the same workload as the primary.

Answer (score 0):

from what i checked there is no problem in having different DTU in replica and primary.
There is however a best practice to have the same service tier between the two
(standard and premium) as to not cause a HADR_SYNC_COMMIT error.